# Cant have passworldess ssh between 2 ec2 servers - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I created 2 aws ubuntu 12.04 servers

I uploaded the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files to both servers

I ran the below on both servers

```
chmod 600 id_rsa*
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

What did I do wrong?

```
ssh ubuntu@ec2-54-183-89-212.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
The authenticity of host 'ec2-54-183-89-212.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (172.31.5.34)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 2a:3a:43:9d:e8:aa:50:2f:f3:83:c4:e2:2e:b2:f2:e7.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-54-183-89-212.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com,172.31.5.34' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Have you added machine1's public key to machine2's `authorized_keys` file? Uploading the keys to `.ssh/id_rsa*` does not make a server accept them for incoming connections.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-add` adds to the keys to SSH agent for authentication in connections opened **from** the server, not for connections to the server. So you'll have to do:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Further, the permission on `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` need not be `600`, since it is the public key. It can be `644` without loss of security.